# Получить поля запроса из ReadOnlyModelViewSet

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить доступ к полям, которые были переданы в GET запросе на ViewSet следующего вида:

```
class MyViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data <<< попытка обратиться к этому атрибуту вернет пустой словарь

        return super().list(request, args, kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно не `request.data`, a `request.query_params`

Вот [ссылка](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) на документацию